# ml64 - warning A6004: procedure argument or local not referenced

Tags: visual-studio-2005, assembly, 64-bit, masm, winpe

I have a function written for th e x64 microsft macro assembler in visual studio 2005.
The function recieves 3 arguments:

```
theFunction PROC firstP:QWORD, secondP:QWORD, thirdP:QWORD
```

the x64 calling convention state the the first 4 arguments will reside in registers rcx, rdx, r8 & r9.
When I'm using the arguments in the function, I'm referencing the register them self and not the parameters:

```
mov r10, rcx   ; Move firstP to r10
```

This causes the following warning:

> warning A6004: procedure argument or local not referenced

How can I avoid or surpress this warning?
Is there any way to reference the parameters inside the function instead of using the registers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution: I didn't need to declare the PROC the way I did. No need to declare the parameters that are passed to the function.

```
theFunction PROC
mov r10, rcx       ;Move firstP to r10
```